# Ruby strange quoting

Tags: ruby, escaping, quote, quoting

sorry for bad English. Why Ruby quoting so strange? Or may be this is a bug?

```
irb(main):027:0> p eval "\"    \+     \\+    \\\+     \\\\+    \\\\\+    \""
```

produces

```
=> "    +     +    +     \\+    \\+    "
```

or

```
irb(main):027:0> puts eval "\"    \+     \\+    \\\+     \\\\+    \\\\\+    \""
```

produces

```
=> +     +    +     \+    \+
```

or another example

```
irb(main):067:0> "  \"  " =~ Regexp.new(eval("\"  \\\"  \""))   
=> 0

irb(main):068:0> "  +  " =~ Regexp.new(eval("\"  \\\\+  \""))   
=> 0
```

Comment: What's unexpected about this?  Or what did you expect to be returned instead?

Comment: I'd say the problem isn't Ruby's quoting, it's your understanding of how it works. In general, when dealing with a language that has been in use for many years, and has a significant amount of code written using it, if you have a problem with a core, very fundamental part of it, then the problem is not the language.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Also known as "Select isn't broken".

Answer (score 2):

When you write `\"    \+     \\+    \\\+     \\\\+     \"` you get `"    +     \+    \+     \\+     "`. After, you use `eval` to execute this string, that contains another double-quoted string. You get, then, `+     +    +     \+`.

`\\` => `\`
`\x` => `x` (se não for nenhum caso especial, como `\n`)

Answer (score 0):

ruby escaping is perfectly good,

eval = evaluate/execute the string